# Which has viruses? Aptoide, or the apps that come with it?

Tags: malware, aptoide

I have heard many things about Aptoide and without any money, I am desperate to get FNAF 2.

But my desperation still makes me ask "Which has the virus? Aptoide, or the apps that it comes with"?

Comment: First of all, it's **Aptoide**. Second, there are no **viruses**, just **malware**. Third, *some* of Aptoide's apps may be malicious, not the store itself.

Comment: Although.... Misguided, The concern raised is fairly legitimate @DeathMaskSalesman

Comment: @DanBrown No objection in regards to that. In fact, I believe that Enigma's answer pretty much sums up anything that needs to be said.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman exactly. Here's hoping that OP marks it.

Answer (score 2):

Since Aptoide is not a mediated source for apps (Google Play is), it goes without saying that it's up to the user to use discretion on the things they get from that source.

An alternative market that could contain apps that may have malware could be described as risky but then again so is the internet - all sites are accessible and you must show discretion in avoiding the bad ones.